# How to add cell value to another cell value?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

How do I fetch a value of one cell and add it to another cell?

I tried doing this but it only adds numbers, if I add the cell I want to add it just adds numbers in the cell.

```
function addProduction(){
  // pop-up
  Browser.msgBox("Added Net Production!");

  // define the cell to be incremented
  var cell = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("E21");

  // get and set the cell value
  var cellValue = cell.getValue();
  cell.setValue(cellValue + "1");
}
```

How do you get this to work:

```
  cell.setValue(cellValue + "D21");
```

Comment: Sorry, not sure of the language but "D21" is just a string of text in that context. Try something like `getRange("D21")`

Comment: Are you trying to concatenate strings?

Comment: In google spreadsheet im trying to add a value to another one by clicking a button, im not sure what coding langauge that uses.

Answer (score 1):

Please try:

```js
function addProduction(){
  Browser.msgBox("Added Net Production!");
  var cell = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("E21");
  var value1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("D21").getValue();
  var value2 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("E21").getValue();
  cell.setValue(value1 + value2);
}
```